# Remeber switch selection in react multi stage form

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a multi-stage form implemented in react and it works fine with text fields. However, recently I have had to add a switch control in the form but it does not remember the selection when I change stages. Is there a special way to implement switch in react with formik?

Here is part of my code:

```
const onChangeCompany = () => {
  diff_company === false ? setDiff_company(true) : setDiff_company(false);
};
```

...

```
<Col md={{ span: 3, offset: 1 }}>
     <Form.Check 
       type="switch"
       label="Different Company"
       name="company"
       onChange={onChangeCompany}
     />
  </Col>
```

...

```
mapPropsToValues: () => ({
  owner: "",
  diff_company: false,
  Company: "",
  location: "",
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

So formik has a unique way of implementing checkboxes still working on switch .. but the following code works.

```
<label>                        
   <Field 
      type="checkbox" 
      name="company" 
      label="Different Company"
    />
    {'  '}Different Company
 </label>
```

I however cannot figure out how to implement an onchange listener!